# Play Framework 2.6 - Allow Guice Circular Proxying

Tags: java, playframework, guice

On old project, we are trying to upgrade Play! to 2.6 version and we are unable to enable circular proxying.

Before (in Play! 2.5), there was possibility to call `disableCircularProxies(false)` on `GuiceInjectorBuilder` but there is no such a method now.

How could be this solved?

Answer (score 1):

In the current solution, I used Scala API in our Java project, because there is still disableCircularProxies available there.

```
class CustomApplicationLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader() {

  override def builder(context: ApplicationLoader.Context): GuiceApplicationBuilder = {
    initialBuilder
      .disableCircularProxies(false)
      .in(context.environment)
      .loadConfig(context.initialConfiguration)
      .overrides(overrides(context): _*)

  }
}
```

and in application.conf

```
play.application.loader = "configuration.api.CustomApplicationLoader"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `disableCircularProxies` was removed in 2.6.x. However, you can work around this by calling `withBinderOptions` directly. [Here's](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/7afc0b54d018642f2c1fb4601e4c0475cd31b876/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/inject/guice/GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala#L84-L91) the 2.5.x implementation of `disableCircularProxies`:

```
final def disableCircularProxies(disable: Boolean = true): Self =
  withBinderOption(DisableCircularProxies, disable)
```

In 2.6.x you can get the same effect as `disableCircularProxies` by directly calling:

```
withBinderOption(DisableCircularProxies, disable)
```

Comment: I couldnt access (or I didnt find a way how to do it) the withBinderOption from Java while accessing GuiceInjectorBuilder but I solved that in Scala API, where the disableCircularProxies is still available.